# Como deixar a lista de itens da Combobox maior que a própria Combo?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

Como é que posso por visível todo o conteúdo da combobox que tenho sem aumentar o tamanho dela?

Hoje ela está assim:

[image: Está assim]

Quero que ela fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Atualização**

Através de um comentário, encontrei a solução [neste link](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup).

Comment: Já tentou diminuir a letra ou quebrar a linha?

Comment: Mas a quebra de linha não fica visualmente bem :S

Comment: Amigo, a única forma é deixa lo grande ou manipular o texto. Tenta quebrar a linha, mas daí você poem algum seletor e tenta manipular ele até ficar em uma posição legal. Por exemplo : <option>texto1<br><span class="alinhar">texto2</span></option> abrs

Comment: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/ tenta te orientar por ai...

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Afinal era possível sem ter de dar quebras de linha :)

Comment: @jsantos1991 poste como resposta

Comment: @vcrzy Essa combo não é em HTML.

Comment: Perdão! Pensei que queria o valor selecionado também. @utluiz realmente preciso ter mais atenção. Valeu

Answer (score 2):

Orienta te  por este codigo:
[link:](http://www.camick.com/java/source/BoundsPopupMenuListener.java)

```
  import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

/**
 *  This class will change the bounds of the JComboBox popup menu to support
 *  different functionality. It will support the following features:
 *  -  a horizontal scrollbar can be displayed when necessary
 *  -  the popup can be wider than the combo box
 *  -  the popup can be displayed above the combo box
 *
 *  Class will only work for a JComboBox that uses a BasicComboPop.
 */
public class BoundsPopupMenuListener implements PopupMenuListener
{
    private boolean scrollBarRequired = true;
    private boolean popupWider;
    private int maximumWidth = -1;
    private boolean popupAbove;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    /**
     *  Convenience constructore to allow the display of a horizontal scrollbar
     *  when required.
     */
    public BoundsPopupMenuListener()
    {
        this(true, false, -1, false);
    }

    /**
     *  Convenience constructor that allows you to display the popup
     *  wider and/or above the combo box.
     *
     *  @param popupWider when true, popup width is based on the popup
     *                    preferred width
     *  @param popupAbove when true, popup is displayed above the combobox
     */
    public BoundsPopupMenuListener(boolean popupWider, boolean popupAbove)
    {
        this(false, popupWider, -1, popupAbove);
    }

    /**
     *  Convenience constructor that allows you to display the popup
     *  wider than the combo box and to specify the maximum width
     *
     *  @param maximumWidth the maximum width of the popup. The
     *                      popupAbove value is set to "true".
     */
    public BoundsPopupMenuListener(int maximumWidth)
    {
        this(true, true, maximumWidth, false);
    }

    /**
     *  General purpose constructor to set all popup properties at once.
     *
     *  @param scrollBarRequired display a horizontal scrollbar when the
     *         preferred width of popup is greater than width of scrollPane.
     *  @param popupWider display the popup at its preferred with
     *  @param maximumWidth limit the popup width to the value specified
     *         (minimum size will be the width of the combo box)
     *  @param popupAbove display the popup above the combo box
     *
     */
    public BoundsPopupMenuListener(
        boolean  scrollBarRequired, boolean popupWider, int maximumWidth, boolean popupAbove)
    {
        setScrollBarRequired( scrollBarRequired );
        setPopupWider( popupWider );
        setMaximumWidth( maximumWidth );
        setPopupAbove( popupAbove );
    }

    /**
     *  Return the maximum width of the popup.
     *
     *  @return the maximumWidth value
     */
    public int getMaximumWidth()
    {
        return maximumWidth;
    }

    /**
     *  Set the maximum width for the popup. This value is only used when
     *  setPopupWider( true ) has been specified. A value of -1 indicates
     *  that there is no maximum.
     *
     *  @param maximumWidth  the maximum width of the popup
     */
    public void setMaximumWidth(int maximumWidth)
    {
        this.maximumWidth = maximumWidth;
    }

    /**
     *  Determine if the popup should be displayed above the combo box.
     *
     *  @return the popupAbove value
     */
    public boolean isPopupAbove()
    {
        return popupAbove;
    }

    /**
     *  Change the location of the popup relative to the combo box.
     *
     *  @param popupAbove  true display popup above the combo box,
     *                     false display popup below the combo box.
     */
    public void setPopupAbove(boolean popupAbove)
    {
        this.popupAbove = popupAbove;
    }

    /**
     *  Determine if the popup might be displayed wider than the combo box
     *
     *  @return the popupWider value
     */
    public boolean isPopupWider()
    {
        return popupWider;
    }

    /**
     *  Change the width of the popup to be the greater of the width of the
     *  combo box or the preferred width of the popup. Normally the popup width
     *  is always the same size as the combo box width.
     *
     *  @param popupWider  true adjust the width as required.
     */
    public void setPopupWider(boolean popupWider)
    {
        this.popupWider = popupWider;
    }

    /**
     *  Determine if the horizontal scroll bar might be required for the popup
     *
     *  @return the scrollBarRequired value
     */
    public boolean isScrollBarRequired()
    {
        return scrollBarRequired;
    }

    /**
     *  For some reason the default implementation of the popup removes the
     *  horizontal scrollBar from the popup scroll pane which can result in
     *  the truncation of the rendered items in the popop. Adding a scrollBar
     *  back to the scrollPane will allow horizontal scrolling if necessary.
     *
     *  @param scrollBarRequired  true add horizontal scrollBar to scrollPane
     *                            false remove the horizontal scrollBar
     */
    public void setScrollBarRequired(boolean scrollBarRequired)
    {
        this.scrollBarRequired = scrollBarRequired;
    }

    /**
     *  Alter the bounds of the popup just before it is made visible.
     */
    @Override
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e)
    {
        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();

        if (comboBox.getItemCount() == 0) return;

        final Object child = comboBox.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);

        if (child instanceof BasicComboPopup)
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    customizePopup((BasicComboPopup)child);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    protected void customizePopup(BasicComboPopup popup)
    {
        scrollPane = getScrollPane(popup);

        if (popupWider)
            popupWider( popup );

        checkHorizontalScrollBar( popup );

        //  For some reason in JDK7 the popup will not display at its preferred
        //  width unless its location has been changed from its default
        //  (ie. for normal "pop down" shift the popup and reset)

        Component comboBox = popup.getInvoker();
        Point location = comboBox.getLocationOnScreen();

        if (popupAbove)
        {
            int height = popup.getPreferredSize().height;
            popup.setLocation(location.x, location.y - height);
        }
        else
        {
            int height = comboBox.getPreferredSize().height;
            popup.setLocation(location.x, location.y + height - 1);
            popup.setLocation(location.x, location.y + height);
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Adjust the width of the scrollpane used by the popup
     */
    protected void popupWider(BasicComboPopup popup)
    {
        JList list = popup.getList();

        //  Determine the maximimum width to use:
        //  a) determine the popup preferred width
        //  b) limit width to the maximum if specified
        //  c) ensure width is not less than the scroll pane width

        int popupWidth = list.getPreferredSize().width
                       + 5  // make sure horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear
                       + getScrollBarWidth(popup, scrollPane);

        if (maximumWidth != -1)
        {
            popupWidth = Math.min(popupWidth, maximumWidth);
        }

        Dimension scrollPaneSize = scrollPane.getPreferredSize();
        popupWidth = Math.max(popupWidth, scrollPaneSize.width);

        //  Adjust the width

        scrollPaneSize.width = popupWidth;
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(scrollPaneSize);
        scrollPane.setMaximumSize(scrollPaneSize);
    }

    /*
     *  This method is called every time:
     *  - to make sure the viewport is returned to its default position
     *  - to remove the horizontal scrollbar when it is not wanted
     */
    private void checkHorizontalScrollBar(BasicComboPopup popup)
    {
        //  Reset the viewport to the left

        JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
        Point p = viewport.getViewPosition();
        p.x = 0;
        viewport.setViewPosition( p );

        //  Remove the scrollbar so it is never painted

        if (! scrollBarRequired)
        {
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar( null );
            return;
        }

        //  Make sure a horizontal scrollbar exists in the scrollpane

        JScrollBar horizontal = scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar();

        if (horizontal == null)
        {
            horizontal = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar( horizontal );
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy( JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED );
        }

        //  Potentially increase height of scroll pane to display the scrollbar

        if (horizontalScrollBarWillBeVisible(popup, scrollPane))
        {
            Dimension scrollPaneSize = scrollPane.getPreferredSize();
            scrollPaneSize.height += horizontal.getPreferredSize().height;
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(scrollPaneSize);
            scrollPane.setMaximumSize(scrollPaneSize);
            scrollPane.revalidate();
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Get the scroll pane used by the popup so its bounds can be adjusted
     */
    protected JScrollPane getScrollPane(BasicComboPopup popup)
    {
        JList list = popup.getList();
        Container c = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, list);

        return (JScrollPane)c;
    }

    /*
     *  I can't find any property on the scrollBar to determine if it will be
     *  displayed or not so use brute force to determine this.
     */
    protected int getScrollBarWidth(BasicComboPopup popup, JScrollPane scrollPane)
    {
        int scrollBarWidth = 0;
        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)popup.getInvoker();

        if (comboBox.getItemCount() > comboBox.getMaximumRowCount())
        {
            JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            scrollBarWidth = vertical.getPreferredSize().width;
        }

        return scrollBarWidth;
    }

    /*
     *  I can't find any property on the scrollBar to determine if it will be
     *  displayed or not so use brute force to determine this.
     */
    protected boolean horizontalScrollBarWillBeVisible(BasicComboPopup popup, JScrollPane scrollPane)
    {
        JList list = popup.getList();
        int scrollBarWidth = getScrollBarWidth(popup, scrollPane);
        int popupWidth = list.getPreferredSize().width + scrollBarWidth;

        return popupWidth > scrollPane.getPreferredSize().width;
    }

    @Override
    public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e)
    {
        //  In its normal state the scrollpane does not have a scrollbar

        if (scrollPane != null)
        {
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar( null );
        }
    }
}
```

exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]